# XPages "xsp://" in rich text - what is that protocol?

Tags: xpages

I am using code I found in the sanple database that comes with the book "Mastering XPages, 2nd edition" - Chapter 11, that has a managed bean to handle the rich text.

in there, it converts html links to xsp:// links.  Anyone knows what they are and how they work?

This is a sample HTML output generated by this bean, for two attachments and an Embedded image:

```
<p dir="ltr"><a class="xsp-inline-attachment application-vnd-openxmlformats-officedocument-spreadsheetml-sheet" href="xsp://Docum2.1.xlsx">Docum2.1.xlsx</a></p>
<p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>
<p dir="ltr"><a class="xsp-inline-attachment application-vnd-openxmlformats-officedocument-wordprocessingml-document" href="xsp://CM034468.docx">CM034468.docx</a></p>
<p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>
<p dir="ltr"><img src=cid:blue_lava_lamp_md_wht /></p>
```

I'd like to understand a bit better how this all works, as we have "invalid persisted content session id" issues that pop up often...

Thanks a bunch

Comment: I am not completely sure about this but after quickly scanning the code and chapter 11 it seems to me that these xsp:// links are kind of "helper links" for any object linked to inside the RichText content (like attached files and images) used for the edit mode (source view). In read mode these links are resolved to the correct http links to these object.
"External links" which refer to external ressources (e. g. other websites) are handled as normal http links.

Comment: The question that is raised then is should we use these type of links every time we make a link to an attachment?  Is this something particular to the code that is in the chapter's sample database or it's something that is across the board in all rich text items in xpages?